# Discord.py latest VoiceChannel.disconnect() doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have been trying to write a discord bot using `discord.py`. `VoiceChannel.connect()` works just like stated in the documents however `VoiceChannel.disconnect()` doesn't work even though it is stated in the documents. I need to use to make the bot leave the voice channel. Below is the code.

```
    elif message.content == ("/bind"):
        channel = message.author.voice.channel
        vc = await channel.connect()


    elif message.content == ("/unbind"):
        channel = message.author.voice.channel
        vc = await channel.disconnect()
```

The error im getting is:

> AttributeError: 'VoiceChannel' object has no attribute 'disconnect'

also I'm using @client.event instead of @client.command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear, [`VoiceChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#voicechannel) does not have `disconnect`.

What you are looking for is [`VoiceClient.disconnect()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.disconnect).

What your code is doing is on the initial `channel.connect()` a `VoiceClient` object is created and asigned to variable `vc`. You can use `await vc.disconnect()` to disconnect from a voice channel.

Another option is to check if the bot is connected to a voice channel on the server/guild using [`Client.voice_client`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.voice_clients), and if so disconnect it from it.

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "/bind":
        channel = message.author.voice.channel
        vc = await channel.connect()

    elif message.content == "/unbind":
        for vc in client.voice_clients:
            if vc.guild == message.guild:
                await vc.disconnect()


client.run('token')
```